# How get absolute path to <project>\taget folder

Tags: java, classloader, filepath

I need to get an absolute path to `<project>/target` folder.
I use the following code:

```
Main main = new Main();
String testPath = main.getClass().getResource("").getPath();
System.out.println(testPath);
```

It returns the path like `/E:/java/main/target/classes/`
But I need to get `/E:/java/main/target/`

How should I set a value in `getResource()`?

In my solution I can not use `System.getProperty("user.dir");` for some reason.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? If you package your application into a JAR to distribute it then you won't *have* a `target` folder anymore.

Comment: After I gave you the answer, you specified you cannot use `System.getProperty("user.dir");` for "some" reason. **What** reason?

Comment: I will get the path and put a file there.

Comment: @Nikolas It is long to explain the reason, here I wonder if is it possible to use another way to get absolute path with getProperty()

Comment: This is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following line will locate you to the base directory, where are the `src`, `resources` and `target` folders located:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

It is the directory, where the JVM was started and those properties are described at [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). The full search would look like:

```
final String targetPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
final File target = Arrays.stream(new File(targetPath).listFiles(File::isDirectory))
    .filter(file -> "target".equals(file.getName()))
    .findAny()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new FileNotFoundException("The target has not been found"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to escape System.getProperty("user.dir")?

Comment: @Auser: Why would you need to escape this statement? What do you **really** need?